# C++ istream operator overload - cant access data member even though declared friend

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

I have a class Complex and I'm trying to overload the istream operator >> to allow the user to input a complex number in the form "(a, b)".  Below is my header file and my implementation.  Right now, I'm getting an error saying that my overloaded >> function can not access the real or imaginary data members because they are inaccessible, even though I declared them as friends in the class header file.  Can anyone explain what I'm not seeing?

Header file:

```
// Complex class definition.
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

class Complex
{
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Complex &);
friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, const Complex &);
public:
   explicit Complex( double = 0.0, double = 0.0 ); // constructor
   Complex operator+( const Complex & ) const; // addition
   Complex operator-( const Complex & ) const; // subtraction
   //Complex operator*(const Complex &); // function not implemented yet
private:
   double real; // real part
   double imaginary; // imaginary part
}; // end class Complex

#endif
```

Implementation file:

```
// Complex class member-function definitions.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Complex.h" // Complex class definition
using namespace std;

// Constructor
Complex::Complex( double realPart, double imaginaryPart ) 
   : real( realPart ),
   imaginary( imaginaryPart ) 
{ 
   // empty body
} // end Complex constructor

// addition operator
Complex Complex::operator+( const Complex &operand2 ) const
{
   return Complex( real + operand2.real, 
      imaginary + operand2.imaginary );
} // end function operator+

// subtraction operator
Complex Complex::operator-( const Complex &operand2 ) const
{
   return Complex( real - operand2.real, 
      imaginary - operand2.imaginary );
} // end function operator-

// display a Complex object in the form: (a, b)
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Complex &operand2)
{
   out << "(" << operand2.real << ", " << operand2.imaginary << ")";

   return out; // enable cascading output
}

// change the imaginary and real parts
istream &operator>>(istream &in, Complex &operand2)
{
   in.ignore(); // skips '('
   in >> setw(1) >> operand2.real; // get real part of the number
   in.ignore(2); //ignore the , and space
   in >> setw(1) >> operand2.imaginary;
   in.ignore(); // skip ')'
   return in; // enable cascading input
}
```

Comment: You need to make the operators public.

Comment: @Barry `friend` declarations can occur anywhere in the class declaration. `private`/`public` doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Really? Cool. Didn't know that (obviously :) )

Comment: Yeah I moved them under public but it doesn't seem to have an effect.  In my book, they place friend declarations before private and public access modifiers always, which is what I did but somehow it is not recognizing them..

Comment: @Barry, makes sense, since a `friend` can access everything in the class, so it doesn't have to be in a public section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is here

```
 friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, const Complex &);
                                              // ^^^^^
```

This doesn't match the (correct) signature of your definition

```
 istream &operator>>(istream &in, Complex &operand2)
```

Comment: Of course, sloppy copy/paste error.  That fixed it, thank you.